# Animating a character with actions from several armatures

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, actions

I'm looking for your input/experiences/suggestions using armature actions built for one rig on a different rig.

I have characters -- and related armature actions -- built from various techniques such as:

- maximo (walk & jog cycles, for example)
- DAZ imports (some custom-built actions like an arm_stand)
- MB_Lab (some custom-built actions like riding a bicycle)

I now want to somehow mix and match in a scene that uses some of these characters, for example when an MB_lab and maximo character walk together side-by-side, mixed in the NLA editor.

[image]

I can think of several strategies that could send me down the worm-hole:

1. Add additional/dual armatures as parents to a given character with Automated weights for when I need to apply an action that uses an given armature.
2. use python to convert action bone references from a foreign rig reference to the characters rig reference.

**TWO ARMATURES:**

If I have more than one armature as parents to a given character,

[image]

I'd be sure that there are no duplicate bone names, so the Vertex Groups are unique for Automated weights.  Armature1 would have "foreArm.fk.L" while Armature2 might have "L.foreArm.fk".

[image]

When I need to apply an action that uses an given armature, I might have to disable one or other armature modifiers during a range of frames, or might have to temporarily change VGs vertex weights (ouch!)

[image]

**PYTHON ACTION CONVERSION:**

The python-conversion approaches would convert Action bone-references from one armature type to another, with bone-to-bone mappings.   This would be complicated by converting actions that use IK in one armature to an armature with no IK, or perhaps easier to add IK to an FK-only armature (maximo).  There might be other side-effects or poor animations where one armature has twist and other auxiliary bones.

```
### set up replacement patterns
def initrep( rep, baseName='' ):
    rep = [ [baseName, "", 0 ] ]    # get rid of basename
    rep.append( ['Pelvis', 'torso', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['Head', 'head', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['L Thigh', 'thigh_fk.L', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['R Thigh', 'thigh_fk.R', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['L Calf', 'shin_fk.L', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['L Foot', 'foot_fk.L', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['R Calf', 'shin_fk.R', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['R Foot', 'foot_fk.R', 0 ] )
    rep.append( ['Toe01', 'DELETE', 2 ] )
    rep.append( ['Toe11', 'DELETE', 2 ] )
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to perform a "Retarget" operation, so that an animation built over an armature is transferred to another armature; changing names of bones and armature modifier is not enough, because also differences in rest pose of the 2 armatures have to be taken into account, expecially rotations.

There are many ways to perform a retarget, both manually or using addons, the most popular is probably AutoRigPro.

Comment: Looks like an affordable winner.