# Use Imported FBX on Rigged character?

Tags: import, .fbx, motion-capture

[image]

Recently I wanted to try out motion capture. Right now I am trying to figure out how I can apply an FBX model to a rigged character. Is there a way I can try and combine the motion file (FBX file) with yhe chosen rigged mesh?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more precise, if you are hoping for answers. What's an FBX model and what's a rigged character in your case? 
If you import the armature from a motion capture, you need to make the character fit the armature.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281059/animating-a-character-with-actions-from-several-armatures/281060#281060